# Postgresql install extension

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-extensions

I installed Posgresql version 10 (stable) through the source package (compiling manually) in the directory opt/pgv10/ .. on my OS LInux Debian Version 8.

I would like to use the HIPOPG extension [1](https://github.com/dalibo/hypopg/blob/master/README.md#installation), [2](https://rjuju.github.io/postgresql/2015/07/02/how-about-hypothetical-indexes.html) to enable the creation of hypothetical indexes in postgresql.

I checked on document (link) you have to have the Dev package from postgresql, but I believe my installation does not have this (I think).

I tried to download the file extension .zip but can not proceed with the compilation and installation (with make and make install), because it gives the following message:
    make: pg_config: Command not found
    make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

On .zip file that I downloaded has the files: HANGELOG.md hypopg - 1.0.0.sql hypopg.control hypopg_import.h META.json test typedefs.list expected hypopg.c hypopg_import.c Makefile README.md TODO.md

In tutorials on the internet, they talk to install via apt-get, but as I installed it manually I believe it will not work.

I tried to run the command:
   create extension hypopg; in psql program, but gave the message below even though I put the hypopg.control files in opt/pgv10/share/postgresql/extension/

```
ERROR: could not access file "$ libdir / hypopg": No such file or directory
```

Would anyone know how to manually install an extension and if it would have to have the -dev package and how would I install that package.

Best Regards 
Neto

Answer (score 1):

THe solution was:

```
$ export PATH=/opt/pgv10/bin:$PATH
-- go to hypopg directory
$ USE_PGXS=1 make install
```

Best Regards
Neto

Comment: Did you know that you can accept your own answer?